# Win7 x64 going to sleep randomly, most often during gaming?

Tags: windows-7, sleep

I have a Win7 x64 on a HP 625 laptop. I've reinstalled Windows twice or thrice because of other problems, but this issue keeps popping up:
Mostly when gaming, but completely randomly, Windows goes to sleep. It's not a temperature issue because it won't ever pass 75 degrees Celsius.
I noticed that it won't happen that often with a fresh install of Windows, but after a while things tend to go downhill.
Is this a update aka software or a hardware issue?
I've found this in my eventmanager: The system is entering sleep. Sleep Reason: Button or Lid.
I assure you that I didn't do any of those things.

Comment: It could be that the sensor on the hinge is faulty, or your keyboard is faulty. I have seen situations where pressing a key on a laptop can cause the system to think that another key was also pressed. Where is the sleep button on your laptop - is it on the main keyboard or is it separate? First I would recommend you change the power settings so that closing the lid does not put the computer to sleep. If that makes no difference, change the settings so that pressing the sleep button does nothing. If you still have the issues we will need more information about drivers etc.

Comment: Are you using the drivers originally supplied with the laptop and do you have any unusual software installed?

Comment: I am using the latest drivers for all the hardware. What do you mean by "unusual software"? I've now changed my settings so the computer shuts down instead of sleeping when dropping the lid or pushing the button. The problem is that this thing is completely unpredictable, so I don't know when it will happen again. Also, I have no sleep button that I know of, just the button I press for the laptop to start and a combination of Fn+f5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something must be broken about your laptop lid. ACPI sensors on the lid can go out of whack. Also, another culprit is low battery life. Try checking your power settings in Windows 7's control panel. By the way, I know that Windows' condition becomes worse every day (my WINDOWS folder is more than 23 gigs!), so see if you can optimize your 7 or try another OS.

Comment: I find it odd to be the sensors, since I've been very careful with the laptop the whole time and I'm moving the lid at all during use. I just stretch the hinges as far as they go, but not hard, and leave them like that. Also, this happens on AC power mostly.